# SMTP transport connection with Microsoft office 365 SMTP server in STARTTLS mode always fails with Authentication Failed Exception

Tags: email, authentication, smtp, office365

I am trying to do SMTP health check with office 365 server in my application (Authentication is enabled, SSL mode is STARTTLS, port is 587). Here is what my code looks like

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
properties.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.office365.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "5000");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
Transport transport;
    try {
      transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
      String username = "authusername";
      String password = "authpassword";
      transport.connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, username, password);

      if (transport.isConnected()) {
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("SMTP connection is established");
        //return true;
      }

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am getting the error as below though the credentials are correctly configured.

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [PN3PR01CA0127.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
```

I have also tried another variant of session object instantiation passing in the Authenticator object but still getting the same error.

```
// DefaultAuthenticator is the class in 'org.apache.commons:commons-email'
DefaultAuthenticator authenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator(username, password);
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
```

Is there anything that I am missing here or related to Office 365 SMTP server? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Microsoft Exchange Smtp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226647/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-exchange-smtp)